# I cannot connect Firebase Realtime Database in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

I am trying to connect to Firebase Realtime Database, but I cannot.

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDDQLlluO4FusOQ8ucJvD_svdMJE5dkOlw",
  authDomain: "portfolio-4dd8c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://portfolio-4dd8c-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "portfolio-4dd8c",
  storageBucket: "portfolio-4dd8c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "237808071168",
  appId: "1:237808071168:web:006dc98a6c3272fbd39ee5"
};
 
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I import firebase from 'firebase' and app.database(), but it give me an error (app.database() is not a function). I also tried import firebase from 'firebase/app'

when I write this import firebase from 'firebase',  terminal gives me error below:

> This dependency was not found:
>
> - firebase in ./src/main.js
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save firebase
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `getDatabase` to get a Database instance using Modular SDK:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database"

const app = initializeApp({...config})

const db = getDatabase(app)

export { db }
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. can you also tell me how can I get the datas from database? I am very new in Firebase

Comment: @OzanBilgiç the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) has examples of both the older syntax and new :)